# Unique query for Merge two column in one which works on MsAccess and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am stuck at one place.

Here this is MsAccess Query :

```
SELECT storage_invoice.PONum,bca_clientvendor.FirstName & "  " & bca_clientvendor.LastName as Name,storage_invoice.Total
FROM storage_invoice,bca_clientvendor
WHERE storage_invoice.CompanyID = 35 AND invoiceStatus = 0  
AND InvoiceTypeID IN(2, 6) 
AND  bca_clientvendor.ClientVendorID = storage_invoice.ClientVendorID
AND bca_clientvendor.CompanyID = 35
ORDER BY storage_invoice.PONum DESC
```

which work fine with Access DB but not in MySQL.

Pls tell me how it will work on MySQL ? also.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Linux commands in windows? similar to this you can't use MS ACCESS Query in MySQL unless the SQL query is very basic. They both have unique syntaxes like square brackets, wildcards, sub-query limitations, functions etc.

If you are using MS Access as front-end, use passthrough queries to execute MySQL query.
if you are using MS Access as query builder, look for an alternative query builder like "Navicat"

Answer (score 0):

`concat` instead of `&` , when you concatenate strings in mysql you use `concat` keyword :

```
SELECT storage_invoice.PONum,
concat(bca_clientvendor.FirstName, "  " , bca_clientvendor.LastName) as Name,
storage_invoice.Total
FROM storage_invoice,bca_clientvendor
WHERE storage_invoice.CompanyID = 35 AND invoiceStatus = 0  
AND InvoiceTypeID IN(2, 6) 
AND  bca_clientvendor.ClientVendorID = storage_invoice.ClientVendorID
AND bca_clientvendor.CompanyID = 35
ORDER BY storage_invoice.PONum DESC
```

if you want run also in MYSQL and ACCESS you can use `+` to concatenate your string:

```
SELECT storage_invoice.PONum, 
bca_clientvendor.FirstName+"  " + bca_clientvendor.LastName as Name,storage_invoice.Total
FROM storage_invoice,bca_clientvendor
WHERE storage_invoice.CompanyID = 35 AND invoiceStatus = 0  
AND InvoiceTypeID IN(2, 6) 
AND  bca_clientvendor.ClientVendorID = storage_invoice.ClientVendorID
AND bca_clientvendor.CompanyID = 35
ORDER BY storage_invoice.PONum DESC
```

Comment: i want unique query which work in MySQL and Ms Access  both.

Comment: @DhruvGurjar try second option

Comment: Gouda Elalfy if we use above both query in mySQL in Name column it will display 0 in place of string.why ?

Comment: RDBMS functions and operators are mostly never the same. There's no way to do this with the exact same statements. the second proposal above returns 0 because the "+" operator in MySQL is there to add numbers, and it returns 0 because your 2 strings are not valid numbers and it thus consider them  as zeroes. The question is: WHY DO YOU WANT TO DO THIS ?